# Python xlsxwriter, add formatting to cell as I write them instead of bulk

Tags: python, excel

Is it possible to apply formatting conditions as I write the data to the worksheet instead of doing this:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('B3:K12', {'type': 'duplicate',
                                     'format': format})
```

So something like:

```
worksheet.write(CELL, "yada yada yada", format=format)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think this is possible.

You can start with a base format:

```
base = {
    'num_format':'#,##0', 
    'font_size':'12'
}
```

As you write you can use the `format.set_` methods to change or add elements to your base format as you write data.

I typically write in a loop like fashion and change the formatting based on the columns.

Example:

```
body = workbook.add_format(base)

body.set_num_format(some_format) # number example

body.set_font_name(some_format) # font example

sheet.write(CELL, some data, body)
```

Comment: so worksheet.write(CELL, "yadayada").format.set_(format)?